# Show that $\partial S$ is the set of points of discontinuity of the characteristic function

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Given $S\subseteq X$, definition of $\partial S$ is the set of points $x\in X$ such that every neighborhood of $x$ contains points of $S$ and $S^c$

> I need to show that $\partial S$ is the set of points of discontinuity of the characteristic function $X_S$ of $S$, where
>
> $$\chi_S(x)=
> \begin{cases} 1 &x\in S\\0 &x\in S^c\end{cases}$$

This question made me think exactly what are points of discontinuity... I know, they're the points where the function is not continuous. I can imagine that a discontinuity will occur in the boundary of the set $X$, because that's when it turns from $1$ to $0$, but how to prove it?

I think that, by definition, a point of discontinuity $x$ would need to have the image $f(x)$ such that every neighborhood of $f(x)$ contains $0$ and $1$. How do I translate that for 'every neighborhood of $x$ contains points of $S$ and $S^c$'?

Update:

what if I try something like $f^{-1}(\{0\}\cup \{1\}) = f^{-1}(\{0\})\cup f^{-1}(\{1\})$? Maybe it helps, but for now I'm getting it to be equal to $X\cup S^c$, don't think that helps

Comment: If every neighbourhood of $x$ contains points of both $S$ and $X-S$, then the same neighbourhood contains points having both function values $0$ and $1$, where the function is the characteristic function of $S$. Can you finish it from here? Use contradiction. Assume that if $x \in \partial S$, then for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that continuity condition is satisfied, and for $\epsilon=0.25$, for example, try a contradiction.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг well, suppose that every neighborhood of $x$ contains points of $S$ and $X-S$, so this neighborhood contains points $p_1$ and $p_2$ such that $f(p_1) = 0$ and $f(p_2) = 1$. A neighborhood of $x$ that contains points such that the images differ is by definition a point of discontinuity? Well, at least for the characteristic function, I agree, but what about other functions?

Comment: You can't say anything about other functions, right? Because we don't know how the other functions behave unless they are specified, right? In the case of characteristic function, your comment encapsulates the approach to be used, so that is good, but for other functions, this kind of behaviour need not happen at all.

Comment: Oh, I should add something. "EVERY" neighbourhood of $x$ contains points with function value zero and one. EVERY is important, one neighbourhood does not suffice at all.

Comment: The [metric-spaces] tag is reserved for questions about metric spaces. If $X$ is a metric space, it is not indicated in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\chi_S$ be discontinuous at $a$ .

**Claim**: $a\in \partial S$.

In order to show that $a\in \partial S$ we need to show that every neighbourhood of $a$ contains points of both $S$ and $S^c$.

Since  $\lambda_S$ be discontinuous at $a$ so there exists $\epsilon_0>0$ such that $\forall \delta>0$; $\chi_S(a-\delta,a+\delta)\nsubseteq (\chi_S(a)-\epsilon_0,\chi_S(a)+\epsilon_0)$.

**CASE I**:$a\in S\implies (\chi_S(a)-\epsilon_0,\chi_S(a)+\epsilon_0)=(1-\epsilon_0,1+\epsilon_0)$.

Since $a\in (a-\delta,a+\delta)\implies 1\in \chi_S(a-\delta,a+\delta)$.

Again since $\chi_S(a-\delta,a+\delta)\nsubseteq (\chi_S(a)-\epsilon_0,\chi_S(a)+\epsilon_0)$ and $\chi_S=0\text{or} 1$,hence $\chi_S(a-\delta,a+\delta)=\{0,1\}$.

So $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$ contains points of both $S$ and $S^c$ which holds $\forall \delta>0$.Hence $a\in \partial S$.

**CASE II**: $a\in S^c$. Proceed similarly..

**Conversely**; let $\chi _S$ be continuous at $a\in \partial S\implies S$ is clo-open $\implies \bar S=S^\circ=S\implies \partial S=\bar S\setminus S^\circ=\emptyset$ which is false as $a\in \partial S$

Comment: You also need to show the converse, i.e. that if $a \in \partial S$ then $\chi_S$ is discontinuous at $a$.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi;Thanks see the edits

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in\partial S\cap S$, then $f(x)=1$, Assuming that the function is continuous at $x$, then one has some open set $G$ which containing $x$ such that $|f(u)-1|<1/2$ for all $u\in G$. As you have suggested, $G$ contains some $v\in X-S$, so $1=|f(v)-1|<1/2$, a contradiction. That $x\in\partial S\cap(X-S)$ is treated similarly.

Answer (score 0):

A function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous at $a \in X$, iff for every neighbourhood $O$ of $f(a)$ in $Y$, $f^{-1}[O]$ is a neighbourhood of $a$ in $X$.

Now apply this to $f = \chi_S$ and $Y = \{0,1\}$ in the discrete topology.

Then $\chi_S$ is continuous at $x \in S$ iff $(\chi_S)^{-1}[\{1\}] = S$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ (because $\chi_S(x) = 1$ iff $x \in S$, and we apply the above to the singleton neighbourhood $\{1\}$ which is open), so iff $x \in \operatorname{Int}(S)$. The same holds for the complement of $S$, using $\{0\}$ instead, so $\chi_S$ is continuous at $x \notin S$ iff $X \setminus S$ is a neighbourhood of $x$, i.e. iff $x \in \operatorname{Int}(X \setminus S)$.

As $X = \operatorname{Int}(A) \cup \partial S \cup \operatorname{Int}(X \setminus S)$, and this union is disjoint (for any $S$) we see that $x$ is not a continuity point iff $x \in \partial S$ (Any continuity point lies in $S$, hence its interior, *or* in its complement and then in the interior of that complement).